# Mosaic overlapping rasters in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, mosaic-dataset

I am trying to mosaic 3 data sets, 2 of which are bathymetry and 1 elevation data sets. The bathy data overlap the elevation data where it has NoData and the elevation data overlap the bathy data where there is NoData.

My problem is I keep getting NoData from 1 or the other dataset obscuring the actual data. This normally occurs after I  Build Overviews. Creating footprints also does not work, ArcCatalog just tends to crash.

I have already created mosaics of the individual data sets and then try to mosaic using these. I have simplified my elevation data set and removed al the little islands and small NoData areas within the data set.

See attached picture.[image]

Answer (score 1):

With large overlaps, I would suggest that you create a single layer using map Algebra. In your map algebra tool, you can decide which data is to be used in priority, e.g.

```
Con(IsNull("elevation"), Con(IsNull("Bathy1"), "Bathy2","Bathy1"),"elevation")
```

In this case, use one of the bathymetric rasters if elevation is null (=NoData)

Note: Make sure that you define the output extent as the max of all extents in the tool environment.

Comment: Thank you. I managed to order by attribute which worked this time. But I will definitely try the map algebra next time, this problem took me 2 days to get right.

Comment: You are welcome. Feel free to add an answer to your own post with your solution, for the benefit of the community.